# Copying color from one gif image to a new gif image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to take two color coded gif images and combine them into one image, plus several other situations where I need to produce a color gif image from scratch.  I can copy from one gif image to a new 'P' image but the color doesn't copy over.  I end up with a black and white/greyscale image instead of an exact copy of the image I started with.  I'm just trying this from scratch to make sure I have process down before I continue forward.  So far I don't have the process down.

```
from PIL import Image

filename = '/media/image1.gif'

im = Image.open(filename);
size = width, height = im.size

coordinates = x,y = width, height
img = Image.new('P',coordinates)
pixels = img.load()

for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        coordinates = x,y
        pixels[x,y]=im.getpixel(coordinates)

img.show()
```

What am I doing wrong to get the colors to transfer over?

Comment: GIF images are indexed color. Did you look for a way to copy the palette?

Comment: I think where I might be lost is the indexed color concept.  I thought the color number would be 0-255.  Like I said initially I'm looking at pulling off the color of the individual pixels and than adding up the values associated with the colors shown and making a new graph with the added value.  I don't think copying the palette would make any difference would it?

Comment: Color numbers are just numbers, not RGB values. There's a map between these numbers and actual RGB colors called [palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gif#Palettes). They say that something like `img.palette.getvalues()` should give you the palette data, you could probably copy it somehow, take a look at the docs.

Comment: I've been reading through past questions and that's the feeling I'm getting.  I definitely didn't realize that the colors(RGB values) weren't fixed values but rather set by the user/programmer.  I'm learning a lot quickly.

Comment: I'm also getting the idea that getting the color palette isn't that much of an issue but I'm not seeing anything that shows how you go about setting the palette.  Do you just create a tuple and put the palette in a tuple and then reference to the tuple for choosing the color.  I know what I just said but doing it is another story if I'm correct.  I will have to play with that idea tonight when I get home.  I might be in WAY over my head.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `im.convert('RGB')` to recreate im's palette manually, since the palette stuff is poorly documented.

```
pal_inds = list(im.getdata()) # e.g. [1, 4, 5, ...]
pal_rgbs = list(im.convert('RGB').getdata()) # e.g. [(255, 255, 0), ...]
pal_map = dict((zip(pal_inds, pal_rgbs)))
```

Then create a new image with the palette using `putpalette` with flattened list of values from `pal_map`:

```
img = Image.new("P", im.size, 0)
palette = [pal_map[i] for i in sorted(pal_map)]
flat_palette = [ind for rgb in palette for ind in rgb]
img.putpalette(flat_palette)
```

And then you should be able to use `pixels` as you were trying before. Also, [this](http://effbot.org/zone/creating-palette-images.htm) might help.