# Give pixels with certain color a different RGB value in python

Tags: python, image-processing, colors

I've got a weather site, but it's missing a personalized radar.
I've found open radar data for my country (the netherlands) but it already has a specific color. I found that python can manipulate colors with the image lib, but i'm not that good with python. How can I get python to recognize the radar colors, pixel by pixel, and change them to a different color? Sample image:

[image: This]
<sub>(source: [weerplaza.nl](http://www.weerplaza.nl/klanten/nos/nos_radar_285.gif))</sub>

Comment: do you want to change color of specific color into another or different colors into another different colors? Can you make it more detail about the result that you want to get?

Comment: I want the colors of the radar turned into a different color. Now you have the shades of blue, wich represents lower precipitation, and i want that to be shades of yellow. And the higher precipitation, represented by yellow and red, represented by shades of red only. I don't know if that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image's type is GIF. It makes the job more difficult because the color of GIF is palette-based, not RGB. OpenCV is not support GIF right now, your best option maybe [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0).

So, according to this [SO's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443120/copying-color-from-one-gif-image-to-a-new-gif-image) you first need to find the palette, then convert the palette to RGB and find which color is in which pixel (which can be done easily by using some tools like [colorpix](http://www.colorschemer.com/colorpix_info.php)).

Next, you change that color in the palette and write this new palette back to the image.

```
import Image

im = Image.open("path\to\nos_radar_285.gif")

try:
    i = 0
    while 1:
        im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
        
        # get color of each pixel
        pal_inds = list(im.getdata())
        pal_rgbs = list(im.convert('RGB').getdata())
        
        # change a specific color to another color
        # eg. (190, 5, 3) to (138, 218, 47)
        pal_rgbs = [color if color != (190, 5, 3) else (138, 218, 47) for color in pal_rgbs]
        
        # remake a new palette
        pal_map = dict((zip(pal_inds, pal_rgbs)))
        palette = [pal_map[i] for i in sorted(pal_map)]
        flat_palette = [ind for rgb in palette for ind in rgb]
        
        # put the palette back to image
        im.putpalette(flat_palette)
        im.show()
        im.save('name%d' %i, 'jpg')
        i+=1
except EOFError:
    print 'done'
```

Since the GIF contains more than one frame, I save each frame as separate image.